# How to use a hard coded key from 1 program in another program (shmget call)

Tags: c++, c, shared-memory

I am new so I need some help. I want to hard code a no. of keys in program 1 and it chooses 1 key from them and use the key chosen by program 1 to be used program 2. Is there a way I can pass the same key to the other source file (program 2)?

Comment: _Ctrl_ + _C_ and _Ctrl_ + _V_ ?

Comment: some1 suggested use mmap() but Idk how to use that

Comment: Call the second program with the key as a command-line or environment variable?

Comment: the program has to be used on another machine.. don't think thats a viable option

Comment: Yes, there are many different ways you can pass information from one program to another, but without more information on what you are doing and why it is impossible to suggest which one you should use.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a simple socket-based communication system. This is the proper option, mostly if you want prog1 and prog2 to be used on different computers. This makes things secure, stable, under control and scalable. Forget sharing memory.

EDIT: I mean a simple client (which ask for a key)-server (which transmit the key) pattern.